# Почему forward_from не появляется когда я делаю запрос?

Tags: python, api, telegram, бот

Пишу бот для telegram на python-telegram-bot. (Делаю копию бота для обратной связи, как у LiveGramBot). Обнаружил очень странную вещь. После получения сообщения от рядового юзера я имею JSON-ответ такого формата:

```
...
'forward_from': 
    {
    'id': *******, 
    'first_name': '**', 
    'is_bot': False, 
    'last_name': '**', 
    'username': '*****', 
    'language_code': 'ru'},
}
...
```

Но когда сообщение форвардится именно от меня, то этого блока данных попросту нет. В чём проблема и как обойти? Может ли быть проблема с настройками конфиденциальности? Или я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Настройками приватности у тебя закрыта ссылка на свой профиль в пересылаемых сообщениях. Ты можешь получить только сендер_нэйм